# VBA - PPT - Batch Import Images - Into Existing Presentation Slides - As Back Drop For Content

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am an extreme newbie with vba, so please forgive my newbieness, and please be gentle with me, thank you.

I need some help.

How do I import images into an existing presentation.

All my slides have text on them. I simply want to import 1 image per slide as a back drop.
I feel really silly - as this seems like a very ordinary task that should be in PPT but as far as i know -  I cant seem to get anything to work.

I would like each image I import to be the back drop of the content on the slide.

I have looked all over for months and nothing has worked.

This macro does a good job of importing the images only

http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00352_Batch_Insert_a_folder_full_of_pictures-_one_per_slide.htm

Code below adds the image and  slide

```
Do While strTemp <> ""
Set oSld =   ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count  + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
Set oPic = oSld.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=strPath & strTemp, _
LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
Left:=0, _
Top:=0, _
Width:=-1, _
Height:=-1)
' width/height of -1 tells PPT to import the image at its "natural" size
```

Can any VBA pro expert please assist me - as I have near to 300+ slides and manually fixing different images is going to be a long week of hard work.

I am very appreciative of your advice.

many thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

After adding the picture, do this:

```
oPic.ZOrder(msoSendToBack)
```

That'll send the picture behind all the other shapes on the slide.

Note that, depending on PPT version, PPT may drop your pictures into empty content or picture placeholders on the slide rather than inserting them normally.  There are ways around this, but if you're using slides w/o these placeholders, or they're there but already have content, we needn't worry about it.

Comment: Hi Steve, unfortunately, once you import images - there are no other shapes on the slide :(   - it just imports 1 image per slide

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what the problem is. Before,you said that there was text on the slides; now, no other shapes on the slide.  And is importing just one image per slide a problem?  How many do you want and what would you want it to do with more than one?  If you want the images to fill the slide, you'll want to set the .Height and .Width after inserting them; the same URL you quoted above also explains how to do that.